# Dynamically get default display form url in sharepoint 2013 by REST or JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, client-object-model, display-form

How can I get default display form url of sharepoint list item via Rest or JSOM.
I found the result by link: 
[How to get the Display Form URL, using REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119236/how-to-get-the-display-form-url-using-rest)

But the XML returns all of the display form url, I don't know how to specify where is the default URL?

I need to get it dynamically!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also use

```
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List title')/DefaultDisplayFormUrl
```

If you want for all lists do

```
_api/Web/Lists?$select=DefaultDisplayFormUrl
```

Note that the property is not visible when visiting `List` directly, need full path or `$select`.

Comment: Hi again, how can I get the results. I use data.d.results[0].DefaultDisplayFormUrl, but it doesn't work

Comment: Try `data.value`. It could alter if you use SPO, on premise or through an app. What you can do is to call `console.log(data)` and you will see the object structure in say Chrome dev tools. Another option is to view it in Dev tools network tab. Yet another is to set break point and inspect `data` variable.

Comment: Thanks guy, `console.log(data)` work perfect then I can inspect the object. Great!

Answer (score 5):

Use `DefaultDisplayFormUrl` at the time of loading the list in Javacript client object model. Example:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
clientContext.load(list, 'DefaultDisplayFormUrl');
```

Then while enumerating the listitemcollection use `get_defaultDisplayFormUrl()` to create the Url. Example:

```
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    var listItemId = listItem.get_item('ID');
    var href = list.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl() + "?ID=" + listItemId;
    }
```

Comment: i also used the same one but it gives mi url like href="/sites/appdev/Lists/Students" List dispform.aspx?id="14"></a> and my list name is "Students List"
and this is my code
  var web = context.get_web(); //Get the Site 
       ListName = "Students List";
        ListName = ListName.trim();
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
   var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
    var items = list.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(list, "DefaultDisplayFormUrl");
    ctx.load(items);